# Declaratively configure multiple input sources under NixOS

Tags: gnome, xorg, keyboard, nixos

I'm using `NixOS 23.05.885.bb8b5735d6f`. I usually configure two language selections set by input sources within `GNOME Settings`:

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'es')]
```

I'm trying to see if there is any configuration within `services.xserver` to achieve the same result. So far the only key that looks like it might do it is `services.xserver.extraLayouts`, but I can't get it to work.

Any clues how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was as simple as adding another value for `layout` within `services.xserver` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  ...
  services = {
    ...
    xserver = {
      desktopManager.gnome.enable = true;
      displayManager.gdm.enable = true;
      enable = true;
      excludePackages = with pkgs; [ xterm ];
      layout = "es,us";
      ...
      xkbOptions = "numpad:microsoft";
    };
  };
  ...
}
```

Initially, I had `layout = "us"`. After adding `es`, rebuilding the configuration, and restarting the system (probably logging off and on could work as well), I can see both input sources in `GNOME`'s top bar — and also verifiable with `gsettings`.

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources 
[('xkb', 'es'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

> **NOTICE:** I had to reset this settings previously (`gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`) in order to see the correct values applied when building a new `NixOS` configuration/generation.

Comment: Thank you for your notice, effectively, we must reset the configuration for the service.layout.layout variable if we would like applied on the user setting